# Join 3 table group by month

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, left-join

I'm new in Mysql. I want to make a chart based on database. I have 3 tables: invoice, purchase, and month. I want to join all of them and group them by month.
I've already join 2: invoice & month and purchase & month. It worked. But when I tried join 3 of them, there was an error.
Below is my code.

```
function get_chart(){

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT month.month_name as month, 
        SUM(table_purchase.subtotal) AS total1,
        SUM(table_invoice.subtotal) AS total2  
        FROM month 
        LEFT JOIN table_purchase ON (month.month_num = MONTH(table_purchase.date_pur)  
        LEFT JOIN table_invoice ON (month.month_num = MONTH(table_invoice.date_inv)

        GROUP BY month.month_name ORDER BY month.month_num");

    $res = array();

        foreach($query->result_array() as $data){
            $res[] = array(
                "month" => $data['month'],
                "total1" => $data['total1'],
                "total2" => $data['total2'],
            );
        }
        return $res;

}
```

Error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN table_invoice ON (month.month_num = MONTH(table_invoice.date_inv) ' at line 6

Comment: update your question and add  you exact error message

Comment: Done. I've edited it and add the error message

Comment: i hav already post an asnwer  ..check for right sintax

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking to your code you have a wrong `(` at the beginning of ON clause  .. try remove

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT month.month_name as month, 
    SUM(table_purchase.subtotal) AS total1,
    SUM(table_invoice.subtotal) AS total2  
    FROM month 
    LEFT JOIN table_purchase ON month.month_num = MONTH(table_purchase.date_pur)
    LEFT JOIN table_invoice ON month.month_num = MONTH(table_invoice.date_inv)

    GROUP BY month.month_name 
    ORDER BY month.month_num");
```